# How does a bare PCB product such as a Raspberry Pi pass ESD testing for CE mark?

Tags: emc, esd

I am designing a product that is to be sold as a bare PCB as a finished product, and so requires EMC testing to be able to CE mark. I am new to designing for ESD, and protecting every single exposed pin from an 8KV discharge seems overwhelming!

My question is how does something like a Raspberry Pi pass this test? Have they managed to design such that every pin survives 8KV, or am I missing something about how the EMC directive is applied?

Comment: um, I'm not an import law expert, but if you sell a bare PCB, that sounds like a *component* rather than a consumer device, and then it doesn't have to carry CE – just like a resistor has no CE mark.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "bare PCB"? I would normally understand that to mean an unpopulated PCB (i.e. with no components fitted), but the question seems to imply that you mean a populated PCB without a case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does [this](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/301400_301499/30148901/01.09.02_60/en_30148901v010902p.pdf) answer your question (emphasis added)?

> 9.3.2 Test method The test method shall be in accordance with EN 61000-4-2 [2]. For radio equipment and ancillary equipment the
> following requirements and evaluation of test results shall apply. The
> test severity level for contact discharge shall be 4 kV and for air
> discharge 8 kV. All other details, including intermediate test levels,
> are contained within EN 61000-4-2 [2].
> **Electrostatic discharges shall be applied to all exposed surfaces of the EUT except where the user documentation specifically indicates a
> requirement for appropriate protective measures (see EN 61000-4-2
> [2])**

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much. The RPi datasheet then says "Whilst it is powered, avoid handling the printed circuit board, or only handle it by the edges to minimise the risk of electrostatic discharge damage."

Comment: It does not matter if the device is powered or not.  An unpowered board is most definitely susceptible to ESD.   The board should be handled by the edges no matter what.  I can't believe the instructions actually say that.

Comment: @KyleB Most ICs have good ESD protection on all pins, probably good enough to prevent any serious damage to the components. On the other hand, a running system will most definitely fault during ESD events, that's probably the reasoning for the note in the datasheet.

Comment: @KyleB  ESD with power applied runs the additional risk of latch-up which kills CMOS  parts permanently because the ESD opens a path for the power supply current to flow in quantity. Not to say they shouldn't have a warning, but one tends more to lead to a bricked unit and possible warranty claims and the other to minor annoyances.

Answer (score 6):

You are right that the Raspberry Pi carries a CE conformity.

Either they write in the manual of the Raspberry Pi that the user MUST use some kind of housing or they declare the product as an experimental board (or toy) that does not need to pass ESD tests and that the usage purpose of this product is very limited.

As you stated correctly: It is hard (if not impossible) to protect a bare PCB assembly from ESD. You could use some sort of coating, but you would still need to protect the uncoated pins.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding on how the regulatory approvals are applied.

Unfortunately it is complicated since different countries have different codes, rules, and laws. But in the end you will need find a test lab to certify your product. UL is one of the biggest. ETL is another. There are many others.

The goal of certification is consumer safety and liability protection. You are hiring a test lab to verify that your product is safe. UL or ETL do not care if the product works, only that it meets the required standards for safety. As part of that certification, you will provide them with a list of where you want to sell your product along with a design specification, a manual, a risk assessment, and samples to test.

The lab will help determine which standards apply to sell into those markets. Examples of standards include NFPA 79. UL 508, UL 61010. US standards, Canadian standards, and European standards are different, although they are many similarities. To sell into Europe, your best bet is to test to the harmonized standards. CE mark requires additional documentation including a technical file and declaration of conformity.

In Europe if your product hurts someone, you the engineer could be liable. That includes being thrown in jail and sued or your company being shut down. But if you have passed the required certifications, and met the required level of safety, done your due diligence, then you are protected from liability. This is the entire point of the process.

This is not cheap. Expect $30,000 or more to hire a lab to do this. A big part of that involves what your specific product does.

Whether your product is component or a complete product has huge implications for how the product is certified and tested. A switch or resistor is a component not a product. It wouldn't make sense to certify to various standards. Instead a relevent is chosing. For example UL508 is common with switches.  Consumer, industrial, medical use different standards and different limits within those standards.

I designed a product that used a Raspberry Pi that went through this process. I built an interface board for the PI where I used optoisolaters to protect the PI inputs. The product was contained in a metal enclosure. There were UL approved power supplies to convert AC power into +5V DC power for the PI. The HMI was a UL approved touch screen.

During ESD testing, they don't open up the machine and zap the pi but they do zap any component that would be touched during normal use. This includes the screen, exposed screws, any push button.

For the AC  mains test, they put various transients onto the AC mains. They check for AC leakage. They verify that the enclosure is securely grounded.

A bare PCB does not sound like many of these tests make sense. I doubt a bare PCB would be considered a complete product. However you will have to work with someone to help make that determination. Good luck.